# [Multiples buttons in a view responding to touch events at same time

Tags: xcode, swift

I am struggling to resolve a multi touch problem in a view. Would be please if you can help me to solve it.

I have a view controller with some buttons in it, and if i touch 3 of these buttons at the same time, all of them will respond to the touch event, and i don't want it to happen (i want it to either one respond or none respond).

I tried to disable multitouch in my view, but it does't seen to work (maybe because it counts as one touch in each button instead of multiple touchs in my view). Is there any way i can solve this without changing my buttons to views?

Thank you!

The buttons action is the following:

```
@IBAction func button0action(sender: UIButton!) {

  jogadas = operations.contadorDeJogadas(sender) as String
  self.count.text = jogadas
  var EOG = baralho.buttonAction(sender, buttonView: self.view)
    if EOG {
       self.whenTheGameIsOver()
    }
}
```

Then I use the sender.tag to perform a individual action, that is different for each button.

Comment: you should use tag then and respond touch of specific button according to its tag....its better if you provide some code with your question....

Comment: I am doing exactly this.
Edited my post with some code